# Getting my input element to right-align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you click this link

http://jaminweb.com/boardBeta.php

and then click *New Thread*, you'll see 3 `input` elements of type `text`, to the right of *Username*, *Password* and *Title*, respectively. I would like those elements right-aligned within their immediate parent `div` (the box with a grey background) or some alternative way of making them aligned with each other. I don't like the look of them being stacked right against the text to the left. I've tried several techniques of accomplishing said task and none of them worked.

Here's the relevant code:

```
div.boardbox
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #00325f;
}

div.hidden
{
    display: none;
}

input.threadipt
{
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

textarea#newthreadtxt
{
  height: 400px; 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

button.threadbutton
{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #DF0101;
}
```

and

```
    <button onclick="$('#newthreaddiv').removeClass('hidden');">New Thread</button>
    <div class="boardbox hidden" id="newthreaddiv">
        <form id="newthreadform">
            <p>Username: <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>
            <p>Password: <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>
            <p>Title: <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>
            <p>Content:</p>
            <textarea id="newthreadtxt"></textarea>
            <button onlick="phpfunction">Create Thread</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Also, I would like that `textarea` element to be centered within the `div` and be only able to expand vertically. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with setting the "float" attribute to "right".

```
input.threadipt
{
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float:right;
}
```

About the textarea, I'm not sure what you mean. If you are talking about the lack of margin at the right of your textarea you can change your CSS into this:

```
textarea#newthreadtxt
{
    height: 400px; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The box-sizing part says that you want the width to be including margin and padding. (in other words; not more then 100%). You can then safely add the margin-right of 5px, which is the same amount as the margin left. This margin is subtracted of the total width, making it centered in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple float right should work.

```
<div>
    <label>UserName:</label>
    <input type="text" style="float:right">
</div>
```

Also think about right justifying your text against the input.

```
<div>
    <label style="width:100px; display: inline-block; text-align:right">UserName:</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#newthreadform > p { position: relative; }
input.threadipt { position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `float:right` to them and that'll do the trick...

alternatively, you could surround the labels with the `<span>` and add a `width` to it - that way they will be aligned as well, not to the right, but aligned

```
<p><span>Username:</span> <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>

p span {
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
div.boardbox
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #00325f;
}

div.hidden
{
    display: none;
}

input.threadipt
{
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

textarea#newthreadtxt
{
  height: 400px; 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#newthreadform p span /* ADDED CSS */
 {
   min-width:90px;
   display:block;
   float:left;
 }

button.threadbutton
{
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #DF0101;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="$('#newthreaddiv').removeClass('hidden');">New Thread</button>
    <div class="boardbox hidden" id="newthreaddiv">
        <form id="newthreadform">
          <p><span>Username:</span> <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>
          <p><span>Password:</span> <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>
          <p><span>Title:</span> <input class="threadipt" type="text"/></p>
          <p><span>Content:</span></p>
          <textarea id="newthreadtxt"></textarea>
          <button onlick="phpfunction">Create Thread</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

SEE THE DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/hPj7S/